# Bridge the gap - Retopology

Tags: topology

I am doing retopolgy on a sculpt. But while doing this I ran into a problem. Please refer to the picture below

[image]

The region I marked with blue marker contains more vertex and the region I marked with red marker contains less vertex. So how to fill the gap in between? I naturally don't want to populate the region I marked with red marker with more vertex. So how to bridge the gap?

Comment: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CncUY.png). However, in a space of less than three polygons, the size shouldn't be reduced to less than 0,3. See illustration on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to reduce vertex count.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgSYv.jpg)

[image]
[image]